# Dynamic component

Tags: checkbox, dynamiccomponent, function

I have a configuration in which I dynamically create a checkbox component.  The checkbox works.  I now want to perform an action when the checkbox changes.  I have the following code.  My onCheck function is not executing when the checkbox changes.  I have a feeling that something is wrong with the syntax in the dynamically created checkbox component.

```
                    $A.createComponent(
                    
                    "ui:inputCheckbox",
                    { 
                        "value" : component.getReference("v.EventRSVP."+ fieldAPIName),
                        "aura:id": "legalnotice",
                        "label": "",
                        "change" : "{!c.onCheck}",
                        "class":"slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--left slds-align-bottom",
                    },
                    function(newInput, status, errorMessage){
                        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                            var body = component.get("v.formBody");
                            body.push(newInput);
                            component.set("v.formBody",body);
                        }
                        else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                        }
                            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                            }
                    });

    onCheck: function(component, event, helper) {
           alert("test");
           var legalNotice = component.find('legalnotice');
           $A.util.addClass(legalNotice, 'hasborder');
```

},

Comment: Updating the dynamic component to contain "change" : component.getReference("{!c.onCheck}"), fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

"change" : component.getReference("{!c.onCheck}"),

Making the above change to the dynamic component fixed the problem.